# Extracting metadata in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a csv file

```
Customer,Gender,Age,City
1,Male,23,Chennai
4,Female,34,Madurai
3,Male,23,Bangalore
```

My Azure SQL DB's table TAB_A has only one column: Column_Name
I need to move the header of csv file into TAB_A such that the result is:

```
Column_Name
Customer
Gender
Age
City
```

Is it possible to achieve this functionality with ADF - Mapping Data flow without using Databricks/Python.

I tried with Source - Surrogate Key - Filter. Able to extract header as row. Unable to transpose. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: The Unpivot transformation should do what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-unpivot

Comment: Hi@Madhanlal Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Please give me sometime. Will verify and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple test and successfully inserted the header into the sql table.
[image]

1. I created a test.csv file, set it as source data, unselect `First row as header`.
   [image]
   Source data preview is as follows:
   [image]
2. Use SurrogateKey1 activity to generate a Row_No column.
   [image]
   SurrogateKey1 activity data preview is as follows:
   [image]
3. Use FIlter1 activity to filter header via expression `Row_No == 1`.
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]
4. Use [Unpivot1 activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-flow-unpivot) to perform row-column conversion.
   **Ungroup by** `Row_No`.
   [image]
   **Unpivot key:** just fill in a column name.
   [image]
   **Unpivoted columns:** This column name must be consistent with the column name in your sql table. This way ADF will do automatic mapping.
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]

That's all.